# PHP Date and Time Format for an API request to Linnworks

Tags: php, date, time, unix-timestamp

IN the Linnworks API documentation and Start and End Date is required for one of the API requests.   The format for this is as follows;

```
 2018-02-19T16:57:07.0049771+00:00
```

I am unsure on this formatting.  Is this a default formatting of some sort or would I need to construct it?

If I need to construct, I get the obvious portions;

Date;

```
2018-02-19
```

Time;

```
T16:57:07
```

But what this portion is I do not know;

```
0049771+00:00
```

Is it the Unix Time Stamp and a + for time zone?

Comment: Microseconds, `u` modifier.

Comment: from [Date documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php): `+00:00` Difference to Greenwich time (GMT) with colon between hours and minutes (`P` format). See also [`DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php#datetime.constants.rfc3339_extended).

Comment: `0049771` is 7 digits, so that would be centinanoseconds rather than microseconds. (I'm assuming that it was a typo and really should be 6 digits, so microseconds)

Comment: I still need to construct this for a now() and a from date. So rather than one word presumptions, and references to the php website, (which I have already searched), maybe you could expand on your answers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, which states:

> Decimal fractions may be added to any of the three time elements.
>   However, a fraction may only be added to the lowest order time element
>   in the representation.

Considering the use of the word "may" here, I would expect that the API should allow you to specify the timestamp without any such decimal portion, assuming that is acceptable for your application. (Disclaimer -- this is a guess.)

If so, this can be had simply via:

```
echo date('c');
```

Which yields:

```
2018-03-20T16:24:37-04:00
```

Comment: Awesome simple, I knew it would be and now I now what it is called, much easier to find the documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: Spoke to soon, both the ISO8601 and DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED referenced miss out the 7 digits I referenced in the example output.

Comment: Yes, and have been reading and double referencing, and googling and reading the php site again, since it was posted.

Comment: "2018-02-19T16:57:06.0303122+00:00" IS the required format.

Comment: I understand that's what the vendor documentation says, but the ISO specification says that the microseconds is optional. Thus, if the vendor has implemented a date parser that complies with the spec, then you should be able to omit the microseconds. Testing it will take but one API hit.

Comment: The API call comes back with an empty response, hence my quest for assistance with the formatting.

Comment: I can get to here "2018-03-20T00:00:00.000+00:00" with DateTime::RFC3339_EXTENDED, but that does not work either.

Answer (score 1):

The end part is microseconds and timezone.

If you use date("c") or $yourDateObject->format("c") it should give you a complete string in this format (ISO 8601).

Comment: Awesome simple, I knew it would be and now I now what it is called, much easier to find the documentation.  Thank you.

Comment: Spoke to soon, both the ISO8601 and DATE_RFC3339_EXTENDED referenced miss out the 7 digits I referenced in the example output.

Answer (score 0):

Format character `u`<sup>(microseconds)</sup> will return 6 char long string <sup>(on php<7.1 it will be `000000`)</sup>.

If you need 7 char long string, just prepend `0` to the end, like this:

```php
$dt = new DateTime();
echo $dt->format('Y-m-d\TH:i:s.u0P');
```

It will output something like this: `2018-03-21T08:47:01.0263140+01:00`